# Field not found: 'Analytics.FieldOutOfBoundaryEventId' after installation of Sitecore Web Forms For Marketers update

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, web-forms-for-marketers

The installation of "Web Forms for Marketers module version 2.4 rev.140117 to version 2.4 rev.140923", in an instance of Sitecore 7.2 rev. 140526, as per [the instructions at SDN](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%202,-d-,4/Module_Upgrades/24_140117_to_24_140923.aspx), results in the following server error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Field not found: 'Analytics.FieldOutOfBoundaryEventId'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: 'Analytics.FieldOutOfBoundaryEventId'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 

[MissingFieldException: Field not found:     'Analytics.FieldOutOfBoundaryEventId'.]
                    Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Pipelines.RegisterValidationRulesEventsMap.RegisterValidationTrackingEvents() +0
(Object , Object[] ) +83
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +365
Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +172
Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +516
System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +530
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Field not found:   'Analytics.FieldOutOfBoundaryEventId'.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618692
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12458309
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you are missing some Sitecore items.

The Sitecore items are needed to trigger goals in relation to Web Forms For Marketers. The particular message you are getting relates to a Goal that is triggered when a user enters a value in a field that is outside the boundaries of the field.

These page events should be under this node in the content tree:

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events`

You should have events such as `Field Out of Boundary` , `Form Dropout` under there.

To get these, you may have to go directly to the WFFM install package for version 2.4 rev.140923. It might be that the upgrade package does not have them or assumes that they are already in place.

Comment: Steps to take: (1) Extract the two .dll files Sitecore.Forms.Core.dll and Sitecore.Forms.Custom.dllfrom the package Web Forms for Marketers 2.4 rev. 140923.update
(2) Rename the existing files Sitecore.Forms.Core.dll and Sitecore.Forms.Custom.dll at the destination (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sitecore\Website\bin) by adding .bak to each of them
(3) Paste the extracted files into the destination (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sitecore\Website\bin)
(4) Reload http://<hostname>/sitecore/admin/updateinstallationwizard.aspx
(5)    Install the "...2.4 rev. 140923.update" package again.

Comment: Credit for the steps in the previous comment is due to George Saadeh of Falafel Software.